# libGDX - Changing FreeTypeFont color with rgb values

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I want to change my font to a specific color using RGB or hex numbers. This is what I have atm.

```
private BitmapFont font;
```

This is my `initFonts()` method called from `create()` in the `game` class:

```
public void initFonts() {

        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Minecraft.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter params = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        params.characters ="0123456789";
        params.size = 150;
        params.color.set(254,208,0,1); //I want to change the color into a custom rgb 
        font = generator.generateFont(params);

        generator.dispose();

    }
```

This makes the font turn completely yellow. 254, 208, 0 is a orangish kind of yellow. What `color.set` I think does is convert the values you put in into one of the already available colors to pick from, like `Colors.YELLOW` for example. What do I do if I want my specific color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by dividing all the values in `params.color.set` with `255f`, meaning it ended up working like this:

```
params.color.set(254f / 255f, 208f / 255f, 0, 1);
```

It's because they want it in a value of 0 to 1, not 0 to 255. I hope this helps other people facing this silly problem as well.